# grails: approaches to importing data from an external schema

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Need to periodically read ~20K records from some external database (schema not under my control), and update/create respective instances in a the local schema (grails' main `dataSource`). The target is a single domain class.

I've mapped the external database as another dataSource. I'm thinking to use `groovy.sql.Sql` + raw SQL to bring-in all records, and generate domain instances as-required. Is that a reasonable path? Should I alternatively model-out the external schema, and use GORM end-to-end?

Assuming the first approach, considering testing: are there any useful tools I should look into for setting-up test data (I.E. an equivalent of build-test-data/fixtures for non-domain data)?

Thanks

Comment: There is hardly any gain in modelling the reading side as GORM objects, because minor changes in the schema there might make you roll out a new version.  With only reading what you need, you could even put the SQL in a config.  Validation is done on the writing end with GORM.  So I think there is nothing left that speaks for GORM beside some convinience functions to query your data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Think this is reasonable given the data size and how often you are going to do this. Just dont forget to execute the sql by batch to save on resources.